# Following a list of values, I want to subset a data frame in r with rows containing the values in a certain column

Tags: r

I have a data frame and want to extract the rows that the value coincide with a certain vector.
In the df, there are no duplicate.
I need the data frame to keep the order of the vector.

```
Name <- c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria", "Ben", "Tina")
Age <- c(23, 41, 32, 58, 26)

mydf <- data.frame(Name, Age)

myvector <- c(23, 26, 32, 26)
```

My expected answer would be

```
"Jon", "Tina", "Maria", "Tina"
```

This is one of the things I've tried:

```
> df[df$Age == to_find,]$Name
Warning message:
In df$Age == to_find :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Also this next solution doesn't give me all the expected rows and still gives me an error message:

```
> subset(df, Age == to_find)
   Name Age
1   Jon  23
3 Maria  32
Warning message:
In Age == to_find :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Use `%in%` instead of `==`

Comment: Maybe try `mydf[match(myvector, mydf$Age), "Name"]`?

Comment: @akun, it doesn't give the answers in the right order...

Comment: @Ben, Thanks! That is working fine! simple and effective

Answer (score 1):

The for loop below returns your desired output. It is also based on the assumption that no two people in your original dataset will have the same age. If that is the case, it simply gets the name of the first person in your dataset who matches the age. For example, if 'myvector' is looking for people aged 34, and there are two people, Joseph and Brian aged 34 in mydf, the new 'names' vector will only get the name of the first person from the dataset who matches the age 34, regardless of how many times you look for 34.

```
Name <- c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria", "Ben", "Tina")
Age <- c(23, 41, 32, 58, 26)

mydf <- data.frame(Name, Age)

myvector <- c(23, 26, 32, 26)

names <- vector(mode="character", length=length(myvector))

for (i in 1:length(names)) {
  
  for (j in 1:length(mydf$Name)) {
    
    if(mydf$Age[j] == myvector[i]) {
      names[i] <- mydf$Name[j]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is working with the simple data that I provided but when I tried with my actual data (df of 59,776 rows and vector of length 10,043) it was taking for ever and I just stoped it to try something more realistic.